# How access properties among different projects in Xcode workspace?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, xcode-workspace

I have a workspace. I have 4 projects in that. Like A, B, C and D. A has appdelegate and other. rest of projects only have classes. I want to use A class appdelegate object in rest of classes. So please assist me, How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: This way you need to link files]

For visibility of files in another target Select file & select check box in the inspector area.
Additionally you can use `open` keyword in swift which is more than publicly available.

```
open class func thisIsGlobalyVisibleFunction() -> String {
        return "global"
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Jack, Thanks for quick reply. In file inspector showing only current target that is A project. Rest of B,C and D not showing in file inspector. By the way. i want to use struct among other projects in workspace. open is not allowing me to do that for struct. its only for class and override methods.

Comment: @srinadh simply use public instead of open. Open identifies a public entity that can be overwritten (not the struct case)

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti I used public. But it's not accessible on other projects in workspace.

Comment: @srinadh Did you update the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS value in the build settings to include the headers of the other project? By default the code is not shared between them

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti i didn't can you please assist me, how can i do it. because i have 4 projects like A,B,C and D. On which project i need to set it.